# C++ Rename function argument when inheriting?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

If I override a virtual method, can I change the name of an argument in the child? Same type of argument, just change say `(int num)` to `(int n)`?

Is this example valid?

```
class Animal
{
    public:
    virtual int foo(int num) {
        return num + 1;
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
    public:
    int foo(int n) override {
        return n - 1;
    }
};
```

If it is, why do argument names not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a proper answer, the names of the arguments do not matter because they are not part of function signature. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function for (quite comprehensive) explanation.

By the way, `const`-ness of the argument itself is not part of the signature either. This way, `void foo(const int x);` and `foo (int x)` are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the response and link! Your comment and Sam's about `const` seem contradictory though?

Comment: @hubatish Sam is talking about the function being marked as `const`.  Not the parameters of the function.

Comment: Also, note that constness is a little more subtle than this. `void foo(const int* x);` and `void foo(int* x)` are two different functions (because it's not x that's const here).

Answer (score 4):

The name of the argument is irrelevant.

The only thing that must match is the type of the parameter.

And also whether the class method itself is `const`, or not. And the method's return value must match.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled the code with an additional:

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Animal a;
    Cat c;
    cout << a.foo(4) << endl;
    cout << c.foo(4) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This ran and gave the expected output of 5, 3.

So it seems changing argument names is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can as long as parameters are scoped to the function being declared to. What matters is the number of parameters and type so be sure that the overriden function has the same `signature` as the base's

```
class Animal
{
    public:
    virtual int foo(int) { // even no parameter identifier and it is ok
        return 0;
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
    public:
        int foo(int n) {
        return n - 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: unnamed parameters are crazy! Thanks for the revelation.

Answer (score 0):

While using virtual method, all you need to do is to keep the declaration of the method same. That is, if I talk about your code you can change the variable number but not the **datatype, parameter list, return type and function name**.